# Good code style introduces whitespace in LaTeX

Tags: syntax, white-space

Suppose I have the following in a `test1.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \section{A section with a very long title which goes beyond seventy-two columns in text editor}
\end{document}
```

Now suppose, for the sake of clean code, I would like to break up the long section title and corresponding brackets into separate lines with a max width of 72 columns as shown in `test2.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \section{
    A section with a very long title which goes beyond seventy-two 
    columns in text editor
  }
\end{document}
```

The resulting pdf from `latexmk -pdflatex test1.tex` is different than the resulting pdf from `latexmk -pdflatex test2.tex`. `test2.tex` contains additional whitespace.

I understand why this occurs, but then how can I enforce good code style without causing extraneous whitespace like this?

Comment: Text is not really code... But you can type `\section{%` to kill the leading space

Comment: Use  `\section{%` in `test2.tex`

Comment: if you had only broken the lines at white space there woruld have been no extra space. Your problem is not the line break it is that `\fbox{x}` is not the same as `\fbox{ x }` white space is just added where you added white space.